# Filter search on specific attributes of an object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to filter some tasks in a table according only to the attributes I'm giving in the table but the search bar also gives tasks that have other attributes matching with the input. Ie there's a boolean attribute and when I type "true" in the search bar, the tasks remain even though they don't have that string in the name i display. Do you know how I could restrict the search to only these attributes ?

```
<input type="text" ng-model="searchFilter">
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="task in taskList | filter: searchFilter"> 
        <td>{{task.task_desc_1}}</td>                                
        <td>{{task.task_desc_2}}</td>                                
        <td>{{task.task_desc_3}}</td>                                
        <td>{{task.task_bv_ref}}</td>                               
    </tr>      
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own pipe (a class which implements PipeTransform with @Pipe annotation).
Overload transform() method like below:

```
@Pipe({
name: 'searchTask'
})
export class SearchTaskPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(tasks: Task[], searchText: string): Task[] {
    if(!tasks){
      return [];
    }
    if(!searchText){
      return tasks;
    }

    searchText=searchText.trim(); 
    searchText=searchText.toLowerCase();

    return tasks.filter(t=>{
      if(t.task_desc_1.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)||
     t.task_desc_2.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)||
    t.task_desc_3.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)||
    t.task_bv_ref.toLowerCase().includes(searchText)||
    ){
        return true;
      }
    }
}
}
```

Add this pipe to your declarations of NgModule. Then in your HTML you can use it as below:

```
 <tr ng-repeat="task in taskList | searchTask: searchFilter">
```

Comment: Check it now. Hope it helps!

Comment: In the end i just wrote a function in my controller that returns true or false whether the attributes i'm testing contain or not the string i give in my search bar. But still thanks for the help !

Comment: If you required the same logic in multiple components, you'll have to copy the code. That's the problem this approach will solve :-)